# Multiple header photos

Tags: discussion

In meta I see there are some photo contest ideas (an event, picture of the week). The reward for winning these contests is that the winning photo will be placed in the header image for a certain time.

Does the SE design allow to rotate the image in the header throughout the day? 
I visit Photo.SE several times per day and it would be fun if every time (or every n-th time) I visit the site, a different header pops up.
This would expose the images of 2nd and 3rd (and maybe 4th, 5th, etc) place winners as well and it would keep the site header more lively.

Comment: Similarly, it might be nice if we could get the banner to have a click event that would link to the hall of fame and/or the voting page.

Comment: It is doubtful that SE already has this logic implemented. I also don't know if we have enough users to necessitate even more "winners" of such contests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the short answer is no. The image in the banner is custom HTML that the moderators have the ability to update manually, which is what @jrista has been doing for quite some time and I've recently chipped in on doing since the election. I don't think either of us are prepared to randomly update that HTML over a course of day, let alone week after week... Mind you, given schedules, it would probably be more random than a computer would generate. ;)

Neat idea, though, so maybe someone working at SE will consider it. Not sure if it's feasible given the variability of the question and answers, so I wouldn't get my hopes up. I don't think the moderators on many sites are given access to raw HTML, so we're already a bit more different than they'd probably normally want from a code maintenance perspective already.